# creating custom scss file

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, bootstrap-sass

I'm install bootstrap gem and follow all direction to change application.css, however when I create another custom .scss file, customizations from the custom file  werent included in application.css.scss . I have tried to import boot strap and bootstrap-sprockets to the custom file as well, but no changes were made on the website. How can I make the customizations on the newly created custom.scss file to show on the website.

the application.css.scss file contains  only 2 lines

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

Comment: could you please rephrase your question

Comment: could you show what application.css contains

Comment: So, is your requirement to add custom.scss to application.css ? could you make the requirement clearer please

Comment: i think what you are looking for should be accomplished by just adding `@import "custom"` to application.css.scss

Comment: I did that as well, but i still see no changes to the website, If I put the customization directly to the application.scss file, then it works

Comment: btw, custom file is trying to style another partial file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've read your question correctly, you have application.**scss**, which contains

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

and also your custom.**scss** file, contents of which you want to end up in application.**css**. You need to add it to your application.**scss** file, ie -

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "custom";
```

It's also recommended to begin the name of .**scss** files which you are importing (also known as partials) with an underscore, so in this case custom.scss becomes _custom.**scss**.

And **make sure you recompile** the application.**scss** to application.**css** so the changes are actually made - I'm not sure what you're using to compile your sass but I think this may be the step you are missing.

Comment: basically, this is what i originally have which doesn't do anything for me for some reason, I renamed both file file with .css.scss extensions so that should already take care of the recompiling problem

Comment: So with the above structure, if you modify custom.scss, then compile application.scss, is what you wrote in custom.scss then visible in the output application.css file? Trying to figure out at which point things are going wrong here.

Comment: oh I figured out what went wrong, I needed to put the `@import "custom"; `line above the other 2 imports lines for the changes to take effect

Comment: Oh ok, interesting. You'd think having it last would ensure the changes would be made, but I guess SASS doesn't roll that way, will have to read up on that!